# PVDF film to record high speed dynamic force

Tags: sensor, frequency

Do you know if TE Connectivity's PVDF films can be used as sensors for measuring high-speed impacts? The frequency range of the signal to be measured is between 3 kHz and 500 KHz. However, there is no information about the frequency range in the datasheet. If anyone has experience using PVDF films for this purpose, I would be grateful for their guidance on which film I should purchase.

https://disensors.com/product/dt-series-with-lead-attachments/

https://disensors.com/product/ldt1-028k-with-lead-attachments/

https://disensors.com/product/fdt-series/

https://disensors.com/product/metallized-piezo-film-sheets/

Comment: If they are these [ones](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7FLDT_with_Crimps%7FA1%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_LDT_with_Crimps_A1.pdf%7FCAT-PFS0006) , they appear to be designed for use in bending mode, which would clearly be unsuitable.

Comment: what about this one? https://disensors.com/product/ldt1-028k-with-lead-attachments/